# Negative Padding in Convolution (Caffe)

Tags: caffe

I have a vector which consists of a concatenation the features of a video sequence across 7 frames.
I would like to apply 1D convolution to this vector such that only a part of a frame is processed.
Say a feature vector for one frame has the length 10

- my input feature vector would be of total length 7 x 10 = 70

Now I want two convolutions to work on different parts of that vector

- conv1 should treat the features 1:5
- conv2 should treat 6:10
- stride for both would be 10
- so the convolution filters apply to the same features only in different frames

Basically I would need to specify an offset for the second conv filter. Is that possible?
On the Caffe website they speak only about a zero padding, but for an offset I would need a negative padding.

Is something like this possible?

```
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 90
    kernel_h: 1
    kernel_w: 5
    pad_h: 0
    pad_w: -5   
    stride: 10
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by using a [slicing layer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html#slicing) instead of negative padding.

Comment: Seems like this would only split the channels into individual layers. Then I would have to change the shape of my input data. I will try if it works...

Comment: It works :). I added a 0 padding for the different channels because the features had different size.